# The image of a smooth submanifold is not always a smooth submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds, $F:M\to N$ be a smooth map, and $A\subset$ M be a smooth submanifold of $M$. What conditions do I need to impose if I want to have that $f(A)$ is a smooth submanifold of $N$?

Some counterexample that I have in mind is $M=\mathbb{R}^3$, $N=\mathbb{R}^2$, $F$ is given by $F(x,y,z)=(x,y)$, and $A=\{(\sin(t),\sin(t)\cos(t),\cos(t))|t\in[0,2\pi]\}$. So, figure $8$ in space which is projected to a figure $8$ in the plane with a selfintersection.

Comment: How do you define a "smooth submanifold"?

Comment: What happens if you project these curves to the $x_1x_2$-plane?  $g(t)=(t^2,t^3,t)$, $h(t)=(t^2-1,t^3-t,t)$.

Comment: @Kajelad, is there a correct common notion to even talk about smoothness in that case?

Comment: @eightc There is a common notion of a smooth manifold; in fact there are several inequivalent ones. This is why I asked for a clarification of what you mean when you say that $A$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$.

Comment: To be less coy, the keywords are *immersed* submanifold and *embedded* submanifold. My examples show that you often get neither.